# Alternative of php's explode/implode-functions in c#

Tags: c#, php, explode, implode

are there a similar functions to explode/implode in the .net-framework?

or do i have to code it by myself?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

[String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) will explode, and [String.Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) will implode.

Answer (score 23):

The current **answers are not fully correct**, and here is why:

all works fine if you have a variable of type `string[]`, but in PHP, you can also have `KeyValue` arrays, let's assume this one:

```
$params = array(
    'merchantnumber' => "123456789", 
    'amount' => "10095", 
    'currency' => "DKK"
);
```

and now call the `implode` method as `echo implode("", $params);` your output is

```
12345678910095DKK
```

and, let's do the same in C#:

```
var kv = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
             { "merchantnumber", "123456789" },
             { "amount", "10095" },
             { "currency", "DKK" }
         };
```

and use `String.Join("", kv)` we will get

```
[merchantnumber, 123456789][amount, 10095][currency, DKK]
```

not exactly the same, right?

what you need to use, and keep in mind that's what PHP does, is to use only the values of the collection, like:

```
String.Join("", kv.Values);
```

and then, yes, it will be the same as the PHP `implode` method

```
12345678910095DKK
```

---

**You can test** PHP code online using http://WriteCodeOnline.com/php/

Comment: To be fair, joining the values of a dictionary is not a common use case.

Comment: @Brilliand it is when dealing with payment providers and their security.

Answer (score 10):

There are two methods that correspond to PHP's explode and implode methods.

The PHP explode's equivalent is [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx).
The PHP implode's equivalent is [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx).