# How to append Hyphens to a string at each nth position?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am getting strings like `"123456"`, `"abcdef"`, `"123abc"` from another application.
I need to format the strings like `"123-456","abc-def"`, `"123-abc"`. The length of the strings can also vary like we can have a string of lenght 30 char. If the 3rd position is chosen then after every 3rd character a hyphen should be inserted.

ex: input "abcdxy123z"
output "**abc-dxy-123-z**" for 3rd position.

if we choose 2nd position then output will be

**"ab-cd-xy-12-3z"**

I tried with String.Format("{0:####-####-####-####}", Convert.ToInt64("1234567891234567")) but if I get a alphanumeric string, it does not work.

Comment: What problem have you encountered that you need help with?

Comment: So... every third character?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to provide us with exact details of what you're trying to achieve, and if possible the code that you have already tried.  It is very unclear what you need, as you have given us 3 examples - all 6 characters in length - told us that the number of character could vary, but NOT told us what format those should take

Comment: The position can vary and the hyphen will repeat on every third position. ex for 123456789012 it will be 123-456-789-012 like this

Comment: OK, so update your question (by **editing** not commenting), give as MUCH *relevant* information as you can. Then the "on hold" status might be removed

Comment: Please edit your post with the attempts you've made so far.

Comment: Actually it's "as much information" **and the code** you're having problem with.

Comment: My problem is that if use string.Format with #, then it works only for numerics.

Comment: You can edit your question directly, you do not need to comment.

Comment: So, the question is how to convert a string, inserting a hyphen at each nth position.

Comment: yes ShellShock that is the question

Comment: I don't see why a reopen is warranted. Please edit your post with your attempts so far; it is a prerequisite instead of just giving us a list of requirements.

Comment: This could be easily done in PHP with `chunk_split` and `implode`.  `chunk_split` equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/splitting-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-certain-size `implode` equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598826/alternative-of-phps-explode-implode-functions-in-c-sharp

Comment: you don't say what happens if size is 3 and len is 3

Comment: @Hogan Probably no change, judging by his "second position" example .

Comment: And don't forget to accept the answer which you would prefer

Answer (score 9):

You could use a little bit of Linq, like this:

```
string Hyphenate(string str, int pos) {
    return String.Join("-",
        str.Select((c, i) => new { c, i })
           .GroupBy(x => x.i / pos)
           .Select(g => String.Join("", g.Select(x => x.c))));
}
```

Or like this:

```
string Hyphenate(string str, int pos) {
    return String.Join("-",
        Enumerable.Range(0, (str.Length - 1) / pos + 1)
            .Select(i => str.Substring(i * pos, Math.Min(str.Length - i * pos, pos))));
}
```

Or you could use a regular expression, like this:

```
string Hyphenate(string str, int pos) {
    return String.Join("-", Regex.Split(str, @"(.{" + pos + "})")
                                 .Where(s => s.Length > 0));
}
```

Or like this:

```
string Hyphenate(string str, int pos) {
    return String.Join("-", Regex.Split(str, @"(?<=\G.{" + pos + "})(?!$)"));
}
```

All of these methods will return the same result:

```
Console.WriteLine(Hyphenate("abcdxy123z", 2)); // ab-cd-xy-12-3z
Console.WriteLine(Hyphenate("abcdxy123z", 3)); // abc-dxy-123-z
Console.WriteLine(Hyphenate("abcdxy123z", 4)); // abcd-xy12-3z
```

Answer (score 5):

The power of the for statement:

```
string str = "12345667889";
int loc = 3;

for(int ins=loc; ins < str.Length; ins+=loc+1)
   str = str.Insert(ins,"-");
```

Gives `123-456-678-89`

As a function:

```
string dashIt(string str,int loc)
{
  if (loc < 1) return str;

  StringBuilder work = new StringBuilder(str);

  for(int ins=loc; ins < work.Length; ins+=loc+1)
     work.Insert(ins,"-");

  return work.ToString();
}
```

Comment: +1 for the second version, but your first code part uses `String.Insert` which returns _new_ string each call

Comment: @Fyodor - true, the first one was done quickly to show how to do it with a for statement.  As a side note, the Linq answers by p.s.w.g create as many or more strings as my first code example.

Comment: Sure! I like it's brevity too, nice example, just noted that the second one is slightly different and get confused a little.

Comment: @Fyodor - I could have used the same code as the first one in the 2nd example but the pass by reference vs pass by value issues would have made the code hard to understand for new coders... I felt this was clearer since it looked like what it did.

Answer (score 3):

With StringBuilder:

```
string input = "12345678"; //could be any length
int position = 3; //could be any other number
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % position == 0){
        sb.Append('-');
    }
    sb.Append(input[i]);
}
string formattedString = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Much faster to increment by position, don't you think?

Comment: @Hogan You are right it would be faster. But I didnt know of the Insert method. Guess I learned sometinhg too XD

Comment: Substring would let you do it without insert.