# PHP function explode to C# for fetching value between start and end

Tags: c#

I'm trying to code a scraper in C#, the thing is I have already made one in PHP but I'm trying to migrate on C#.

Can this possibly be converted on C# as I'm not yet good in coding with this language.

PHP Function:

```
function fetchValue($string,$start,$end){
    $str = explode($start,$string);
    $str = explode($end,$str[1]);
    return $str[0];
}
```

What it exactly does is it extracts the first occurence string between the START and the END.

How is it used:

```
$exampleString = "long live stackoverflow";
$fetchString = fetchValue($exampleString,"long "," stackoverflow";
echo $fetchString;
```

This will then output the word "live" as the START was "long" and the END was "stackoverflow"

Every answers will much be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598826/alternative-of-phps-explode-implode-functions-in-c-sharp

Comment: Hi @Amy thank you for your response. Could you possibly give an example using it? Much appreciated!

Comment: The C# String class already has a method that does that called `Split`

Comment: If you need an example of calling a function in C#, perhaps you should do some tutorials.  This is pretty basic.  Also, the documentation for the methods in the accepted answer provides you examples.

Comment: What you could do is something like. `var str = string.Split(start); var str2 = str[1].Split(end); return str2[0];`

Comment: Hi @SomerandomITboy How does this exactly start if there is no basis for the start and the end :/ btw thank you for reply

Comment: @CedeeCQ see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Split` method from the C#'s `String` class; see this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Don't forget to add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` along with the other `using` statements

```
public string ExtractValue(string source, string start, string end) {
    string[] str = Regex.Split(source, start);
    string[] str2 = Regex.Split(str[1], end);
    return str2[0];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your approach and the effort yet unfortunately I'm unable to use it due to error: Cannot convert from string to char

Comment: Any possible fix about it?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I really appreciate it. Accepted this as an answer. But btw, do you think this is the best approach in doing such task?

Comment: I imagine you're going to use this to extract values from child nodes in the `DOM` and you're going to call it like `string child = ExtractValue(parent, "<div>",<div/>");`. Regular expressions are quite effective when it comes to parsing text they are used by compilers all around the world.